# How to remove a component using Pynecone

Tags: python, html, css, node.js, pynecone

I am trying to remove a parent hstack when a button is pressed. Looked in the Docs and everywhere but couldn't find anything useful.

[image]

From the picture above, when the 'x' button is pressed it should remove the whole option row. Thanks in advance for all the help.